firebase vite build auth.ts (1:29): "signInWithPopup" is not exported by "node_modules/firebase/auth/dist/esm/index.esm.js", imported by "methods.ts"
Qwikjs in dev mode signinwithpopup is running without any problem. But when i'm building using vite build, It's giving error as "src/utils/LoginMethods.ts (1:29): "signInWithPopup" is not exported by "node_modules/firebase/auth/dist/esm/index.esm.js", imported by "src/utils/LoginMethods.ts"."
The firebase versions i used are, 10.14.0 , 10.4.0(I used this version in angular for signinwith popup and it worked fine) and 10.7.1. I changed the versions and tried to build, they worked in dev mode but failed to build
LoginMethod.ts
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup, getIdToken } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "./firebase";
import { LocalStorageUtil } from "./localStorage";
import { Constants } from "./constants";

export class LoginMethods {
  static handleGoogleLogin = async () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    try {
      const response = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
      const token = await getIdToken(response.user);
      LocalStorageUtil.setData(Constants.userKey, token);
      return token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  static handleLinkedinLogin = async () => {
    LocalStorageUtil.setData(Constants.linkedinReturnUrlKey, location.href);
    const linkedinUrl = `${Constants.linkedinUrl}&${Constants.linkedinStateKey}=${window.location.href}&${Constants.linkedinScopeKey}=${Constants.linkedinScope}`;
    window.location.href = linkedinUrl;
  };
}


firebase.ts
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const FIREBASE_API_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY as string;
const FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN = import.meta.env
  .VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN as string;
const FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID = import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID as string;
const FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET = import.meta.env
  .VITE_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET as string;
const FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID = import.meta.env
  .VITE_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID as string;
const FIREBASE_APP_ID = import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_APP_ID as string;

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);

I changed versions like latest 10.14.0 to 10.7.1 and to 10.4.0 but didnt work. I'm expecting to loginwith popup for google, email signin and email signup(works in dev mode properly but build fails)
